# Splitting array if empty value

Tags: php

I am trying to split an array if one of the lines has an empty value. My array is being exported to a csv and has multiple lines of data, if the data is not complete it will be sent to a uncomplete csv and if it is complete it will be sent a complete csv.

This is what my array structure looks like the blank field on the first line is on email (this line should be split out of the array:

```
array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(6) { 
        ["Username"]=> string(47) " STARRY NIGHT CINEMA - RISE OF THE GUARDIANS " 
        ["Email"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["Location"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["Type"]=> int(1) 
        ["Title"]=> string(47) " STARRY NIGHT CINEMA - RISE OF THE GUARDIANS " 
        ["Description"]=> string(491) "the Tooth Fairy"
    }
    [1]=> array(6) { 
        ["Username"]=> string(26) "Maui Nui Botanical Gardens" 
        ["Email"]=> string(18) "info@mnbg.org" 
        ["Location"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["Type"]=> int(1) 
        ["Title"]=> string(26) "Maui Nui Botanical Gardens" 
        ["Description"]=> string(50) "Conserving Hawaiian Plants & Cultural Heritage"
    }
}
```

Writing to my csv:

```
    $fp = fopen('entries.csv', 'w');
    foreach ($entries as $fields) {
        fputcsv($fp, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp);

    if (!copy("http://www.simonstaton.co.uk/entries.csv", "entries.csv")) {
        echo ("failed to copy file");
    };
```

I have no idea where to start with this and as to what function I should use so any advice is greatly appreciated.

Simon

Comment: What do you mean by split out of the array? What would your end result look like?

Comment: So you want 2 different csv files from what I can understand?

Comment: yes that is correct, also thankyou for the reply. I want to have the data split out the lines that have empty fields. Then leave in the lines that are complete and the lines it has split out put in a new array where I can send to a second csv

Comment: If you take out the empty fields, won't your CSVs not have the data in the right columns?

Comment: The empty fields do not need taking out, the line with an empty field does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To separate the entries by complete or incomplete you can open two files for writing. One to contain each.

```
// filenames
$fn_complete = 'entries.csv';
$fn_incomplete = 'incomplete_entries.csv';

// file pointers
$fp_complete = fopen($fn_complete, 'w');
$fp_incomplete = fopen($fn_incomplete, 'w');

// write CSVs
foreach ($entries as $fields) {
    if (in_array('', $fields))
        fputcsv($fp_incomplete, $fields);
    else
        fputcsv($fp_complete, $fields);
}

fclose($fp_complete);
fclose($fp_incomplete);

if (!copy('http://www.simonstaton.co.uk/' . $fn_complete, $fn_complete)) {
    echo ('failed to copy file ' . $fn_complete);
};
if (!copy('http://www.simonstaton.co.uk/' . $fn_incomplete, $fn_incomplete)) {
    echo ('failed to copy file ' . $fn_incomplete);
};
```

Comment: Okay this looks like it would do the job, let me try it

Comment: Okay this just seems to write the same data onto both the csv's and then strip the email field from the one where it was empty

Comment: This won't strip anything. If there is missing data from an entry it puts it in the incomplete file. If the data is complete it puts it in the complete file. None of the data is altered.

Comment: Hmm okay, maybe there is something else causing the problem then. As the csv's it exports look the same however in the blank email field for the top array is the email field from the bottom array.

Comment: Hmmm this is still not working, the second csv is now blank and the first one is still doing the same. What I am wanting it to do is to grab the entire array if it has an empty field inside then put that array onto the incomplete csv. Then put the rest of the array without this one on the cmoplete csv. So the incomplete should have the top array and the complete the second array

Comment: Okay sorry there was an error in my script, the array was actually echoing the same email variable as I had not set it as empty at the start of the loop. Is working now, thankyou very much for this awesome script :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if any of the values in your array is empty like this:

```
in_array('', $array)
```

so it then you can do a simple if

```
if(in_array('', $array)) {
    //Do whatever you have to do to slip your array. I don't understand exactly what you want the end result to look like .
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, am just giving this a go now.

Comment: Okay am just playing with this, however how can I get it to remove the line from the array?

Answer (score 0):

First pack your CSV data into an array using `fgetcsv()`. Then use a loop to search for "". 
Exemplar:

```
$row = 1;
if (($resource = fopen("example.csv", "r")) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($resource, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if ($data[$c] == "") { 
               // operate 
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

By the way, don't use the `split()` function. Use [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: The data is already in an array. There is no reason to read from a CSV.